# Evaluation of a scam contract that steals token when approving

Tags: solidity

---

Hi everyone. I recently bought this token contract address : 0x1c16fa5806F4049003f73C3Ad9c8eD24eAF87924. On approval, the token was sent to the token creator's address. I can't seem to figure out how it was done. I don't see anything wrong with the approve function, but I know it is being overridden, but I have no idea. I am building a bot to avoid such tokens, so knowing how it operates will help. Here is the owner address :  0x2f500fe8ba1f7709f079f35aee71d329d4cb583f . I see logs of approval, meaning this is what is done. What am I missing guys?

Comment: Reading this medium article  [link](https://medium.com/mycrypto/bad-actors-abusing-erc20-approval-to-steal-your-tokens-c0407b7f7c7c)  made me understand how it was done. STAY SAFU GUYS

Comment: I am working on smth similar, let me know if you managed to build your bot

Comment: Did you read what you approving?, usually because approve function an transfer function looks different users don't care about approve function.